# how to quickly iterate functions one by one

Tags: r, performance

i have some data

```
set.seed(1)
n <- 100
df <- data.frame(
  x = sample(1:30, n, replace = T),
  y = sample(1:30, n, replace = T),
  z = sample(1:30, n, replace = T)
)
```

And also i have list of functions, the number of functions can be any, the complexity of the functions too (I intentionally made them simple for this example)

```
rules <- list(function(i) df$x[i]==26,
              function(i) df$y[i]==17,
              function(i) df$z[i]==14)
```

Next, I have a function that sequentially searches for the triggering of the first function, then the second, and so on

```
# search sequence
# first x[i]==26 then y[i]==17 then z[i]==14
find_rules <- function(df, rules){
ln <- length(rules)
n <- 1
res <- matrix(0,nrow = ln, ncol = 2, dimnames = list(NULL, c("row","res")))
for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
  if(rules[[n]](i)){
    res[n,"row"] <- i
    res[n,"res"] <- 1
    n <- n+1
  }
  if(n==ln+1) break
}
return(res)
}
```

I would like to speed up  `find_rules` function as much as possible without changing anything in the code presented above.
I would also like complete identity in the calculations of your solution and `find_rules` on different `seeds()`

Comment: Hi mr.T actually the full script seems to be subject to refactoring as it is written entirely not in an R'ly way. As of the provided sample loops are not needed at all and though the code can be corrected in this part the correction is senseless without rewriting the functions in `rules` list as they are element-wisely designed. Could you specify the general task you are solving so that we could think of a diferent aproach?

Comment: @asd-tm  Hi, Ok, please show your solution with complete refactoring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to keep your code as much as possible but we can change the way of iterating, i.e., by `rules`

```
find_rules_TIC <- function(df, rules) {
    res <- matrix(0, nrow = length(rules), ncol = 2, dimnames = list(NULL, c("row", "res")))
    rid <- seq_len(nrow(df))
    for (i in seq_along(rules)) {
        k <- which(rules[[i]](rid))
        res[i, "row"] <- k[k >= res[ifelse(i == 1, 1, i - 1), "row"]][1]
        res[i, "res"] <- 1
    }
    res
}
```

which should be faster than your original solution if ***the number of rules is less than the number of `df` rows***.

## benchmark

```
find_rules_mrT <- function(df, rules) {
    ln <- length(rules)
    n <- 1
    res <- matrix(0, nrow = ln, ncol = 2, dimnames = list(NULL, c("row", "res")))
    for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
        if (rules[[n]](i)) {
            res[n, "row"] <- i
            res[n, "res"] <- 1
            n <- n + 1
        }
        if (n == ln + 1) break
    }
    return(res)
}

find_rules_TIC <- function(df, rules) {
    res <- matrix(0, nrow = length(rules), ncol = 2, dimnames = list(NULL, c("row", "res")))
    rid <- seq_len(nrow(df))
    for (i in seq_along(rules)) {
        k <- which(rules[[i]](rid))
        res[i, "row"] <- k[k >= res[ifelse(i == 1, 1, i - 1), "row"]][1]
        res[i, "res"] <- 1
    }
    res
}

find_rules_TIC2 <- function(df, rules) {
    rid <- seq_len(nrow(df))
    cbind(
        row = Reduce(\(a, b) b[b >= a][1],
            lapply(rules, \(f) which(f(rid))),
            init = -Inf,
            accumulate = TRUE
        )[-1],
        res = 1
    )
}

microbenchmark(
    find_rules_mrT(df, rules),
    find_rules_TIC(df, rules),
    find_rules_TIC2(df, rules),
    check = "equal",
    unit = "relative"
)
```

and we see that

```
Unit: relative
                       expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq
  find_rules_mrT(df, rules) 3.825137 3.710938 3.420265 3.628788 3.462264
  find_rules_TIC(df, rules) 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000
 find_rules_TIC2(df, rules) 1.098361 1.093750 3.288799 1.093434 1.127358
      max neval
  2.89117   100
  1.00000   100
 99.19507   100
```

Comment: Thank you. If you have an ability? you can show how you would do it without any restrictions